# Ebean change Postgres schema at runtime

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, database-schema, ebean

I discovered ebean with the play framework 2 a few time ago. I really like the way to use the query to access the database. But now I have some problems. I want to write a multi tenancy saas application. Every customer should have an own schema in the PostgreSQL database.

I do not find a way to change the schema at run time. Sure, you can create a new ebean server with a customized config naming the schema. But I think this is to heavy for every request. I also saw that their Is there a way to change the schema in a more elegant way at run time and if not which class do I have to extend to build in such a function? Where is the table name build at run time?

Comment: No solutions, yet !